# how can I prevent matching an all-whitespace line inside brackets with perl regex?

Tags: perl, whitespace, regex-lookarounds, brackets

I want my regex to match the contents of a pair of curly brackets, aka curly braces,
subject to two restrictions.

**Restriction 1:**
The contents are allowed to contain inner pairs of curly brackets, but not recursively---that is, no inner pair is allowed to contain an even deeper pair.

Reason for forbidding recursive nesting is
that the texts that I parse do not contain nested curly brackets.
And if I allow recursive bracket nesting in the regex,
when the desired pattern does not exist
the regex engine can run out of memory searching for one.
Causes more problems than it solves.

**Restriction 2:** The contents must not contain an all-whitespace line.

My code below prevents recursion with brackets but it only manages to prevent **some** all-whitespace lines.

The code below "practices" on 5 separate strings.
It performs as desired on the first 4 strings.
But on the 5th string, it appears that `[{][^{}]*[}]` permits an all-white line to slip through
because the all-white line is "hidden" inside an inner pair of curly brackets.

How can I forbid **all** all-white lines?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
use feature 'say';

my $sgx=join('',      # string that compiles as a regex
'(?m)^',              # anchor start of line, not start of string
'(?<curl>[{]',        # curlybracket BEG
  '(?<insd>',         # insd BEG
    '(?<jjjj>\w)',    # our_special_thing
    '(',              # permitted after our_special_thing : begin
      '(?!\n\s*\n)',  # negative lookahead: not followed by an all-white line https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns
      '[^{}]',        # character other than left or right curly bracket
      '|',            # logical OR 
        '(',            # inner curlybracket BEG
          '[{]',          # inner {
             '[^{}]*',       # any character other than curly bracket (not recursive) 
          '[}]',          # inner }
        ')',            # inner curlybracket END
    ')',              # permitted after our_special_thing : end
    '*',              # any amount of either of these
  ')',                # insd END
'[}])',               # curlybracket END
);

say qr/$sgx/;
$/=undef;
my $data=<DATA>;
my@data=grep{/\S/} split /#/,$data;

for(@data)
{
    say '====================================================================================';
    print $_;
    say '------------------------------------------';
    if($_=~/$sgx/)
    {
        print Dumper\%+;
    }
    else
    {
        say 'no match';
    }
}


__DATA__
#
{A{hey{nested{nested, 

also all-white line, two reasons
SHOULD NOT MATCH}}}}pig
#
{A{hey{nested{nested, SHOULD NOT MATCH}}}}pig
#
whoopee
{compliant, should match
\footnotesize{funny}\normalsize{}\small{}} 
dogs\textbf{outside}
# 
{MUST NOT MATCH because all-white line

tag{A}big{}}
# 
{MUST NOT MATCH because all-white line
tag{A

}big{}}
```

Comment: Is your actual data RTF files? Or Tex/LaTeX?

Comment: (Also, look up the `x` modifier to regular expressions instead of using a bunch of strings joined together)

Comment: LaTeX. To simplify the problem, I removed the `\section`, etc. I am aware of the `x` modifier, but with `x` can I put easy-to-read comments into the code, as I do here? Comments to explain every single little symbol, for a year later when I've forgotten how I did it.

Comment: Yup, you can embed comments. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#/x-and-/xx